# Unable to return top record in a T-SQL scalar function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here's my function which is supposed to return the top row of the record:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_PAT_LastTS] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @PATcode varchar(50)
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @lastTS datetime

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SET @lastTS = (select top 1 tsdate from timesheet where pat = @PATcode order by tsdate desc)

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @lastTS

END
```

For some reason, it always returns all records instead of the top one. Does 'Top' work at all within T-SQL scalar function?

Edit 1: this is how I call the function.

```
select dbo.fn_PAT_LastTS('ZZ793843') from timesheet
```

Edit: added the picture of returned data which showed multiple rows instead of the top 1.[image]

Comment: What do you mean when you say it always returns all records? What exactly is happening?

Comment: What do you mean "returns all records instead of the top one"?  A scalar function only returns one value.  Perhaps you should edit your question with the code that is calling the function.

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: sorry for the confusion - I realised I didn't provide sufficient information in my question - will try my best to provide and explain. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @lastTS = tsdate FROM timesheet WHERE pat = @PATcode ORDER BY tsdate DESC
```

## EDIT:

The problem is with how you're calling the function:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_PAT_LastTS('ZZ793843') FROM timesheet
```

This will select all rows from `timesheet` with one column whose value is the result of `dbo.fn_PAT_LastTS('ZZ793843')`. You should be calling it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM timesheet WHERE tsdate = dbo.fn_PAT_LastTS('ZZ793843')
```

OR

```
SELECT dbo.fn_PAT_LastTS('ZZ793843')
```

Comment: thanks - but that's how I did it in the first place - it doesn't work.

Comment: thanks again - I was calling the function incorrectly which picks up all rows from timesheet table. SELECT dbo.fn_PAT_LastTS('ZZ793843') returns only 1 row of data which is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

The scalar is being called for each row in timesheet.

Try the following:

```
select dbo.fn_PAT_LastTS('ZZ793843')
```

Comment: thank you very much - that works - sorry I had to pick the other one as the answer as he answered earlier.

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify the whole thing by just using:

```
select max(tsdate) as tsdate 
from timesheet 
where pat = @PATcode
```

Comment: thanks - that works perfectly as well - do you know which method is better practice in terms of performance? top or max?

Comment: I would guess that MAX would be faster especially if you have an index on that column - but really the difference will be immaterial.  Using MAX is clearer to the reader and simpler.

Comment: thanks - yes it does look cleaner using max in terms of syntax. thanks again for pointing this out.

Comment: @jiaoziren There is a saying: "write for the reader".  and I believe in that because most of the time the reader of my work is me :)

Comment: true - I'm also concerned about performance and I'd rather have complex code to improve performance than simple code to burden my already underpowered server :-D

Comment: @jiaoziren Complex code does not improve performance, the opposite is true.

Comment: Everything Should Be Made as Simple as Possible, But Not Simpler - Albert Einstein